# General polynomial form of a factorial?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, number-theory

Is anyone aware if there is a general polynomial form of a factorial?  For instance;

- $2!=2^2-2^1$
- $3!=3^3-3(3^2)+2(3^1)$
- $4!=4^4-6(4^3)+11(4^2)-6(4^1)$
- $5!=5^5-10(5^4)+35(5^3)-50(5^2)+24(5^1)$

that is, is there some way of predicting the coefficients for the general form:

$$n!=(n^n)+x'(n^(n-1))+x''(n^(n-2))+.......+y(n^1)$$

obviously, there is the form;

$$n!=n(n-1)\dots(3)(2)(1)$$
but I am interested if there is another way of representing a factorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some keywords: Pochhammer symbol, falling factorials. The coefficients you are looking at are the Stirling number of the first kind, [oeis link](http://oeis.org/A054654)